# Как в C# добавить задержку при выполнении цикла?

Tags: c#

Как в C# добавить задержку при выполнении цикла?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Посмотрите офф. доку на [Thread.Sleep Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(VS.80).aspx).

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Comment: а если использовать await Task.Delay(50) будет не эффективнее?

Comment: С тех пор, как изобрели TAP `await Task.Delay()` рулит, а этот ответ превратился во вредный совет. Но вопрос был задан в 2012 году.

Answer (score 2):

Отлично подошёл метод асинхронный:

```cs
await Task.Delay()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще если в Unity вовремя цикла сделать задержку надо, есть хороший вариант с Coroutine:

```
bool isBusy = false;
public GameObject[] players = new GameObject[4];

private void Update()
{
    if (!isBusy)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
    }
}

IEnumerator Wait() {
    isBusy = true;
    foreach (GameObject player in players) {
        Debug.log("player="+player.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        StopCoroutine(Wait());
    }
    isBusy = false;
}
```

В WaitForSeconds передаёшь просто на какой промежуток времени задерживать.

Comment: Тут хоть слово есть о Unity?

Comment: @And в Unity на С# пишут

Answer (score -2):

Я так делаю *(по сути это тоже самое что сделал Alex Kapustin только вызов слегка иной )* :

```
// подключ. библиотеки
using System;
using System.Threading;

...
Thread.Sleep(1000); // засыпаем на одну секунду
```